# Resetting TweetDeck password is not working

Tags: passwords, tweetdeck

Resetting the TweetDeck password from the desktop client is not working. I tried about 5 or 6 times, it always said that a mail was sent and it never arrived. All support and contact channels at TweetDeck are closed. Does anybody know of an alternative way to contact them or to reset the password? Anybody else suffering this?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to reset your password is through the [web login page](https://www.tweetdeck.com/login/). If you haven't, be sure to check your spam folder.

It appears as if the TweetDeck password reset may be broken at the moment or at least experiencing delays. I've personally tried to reset my password approximately 15 minutes ago and am yet to receive a response-- my old password still works.

Since TweetDeck has been aquired by Twitter it may not be a silly idea to tweet to [Twitter support (@Support)](http://twitter.com/#!/Support), or fill out their [troubleshooting form](https://support.twitter.com/forms).